# callin' c from lua crashs while reallocating

Tags: c, lua, malloc, realloc

i got a crazy error within that for-loop

```
matr=realloc(matr, newmax*sizeof(matr*));

for (i=0; i<newmax; i++){
    matr[i]=realloc(matr[i], newmax*sizeof(int));
}
```

matr is a multi-dimension array: int **matr. i need to resize column and row. first line resizes column and the for-loop resizes every row. it worked fine in c. now im working on a library for lua and it crashs here. compilin' works fine as well. but calling from lua crashs with

```
lua: malloc.c:3552: mremap_chunk: Assertion `((size + offset) & (mp_.pagesize-1)) == 0' failed.
```

i have no damn idea since it's working fine using it in c.

Comment: Are pointers to 'matr' stored inside the lua interpreter? Maybe the interpreter uses the old pointer somewhere after the array got reassigned.

Comment: mtr is part of a struct in c. and that struct is represented as userdata for lua.

Comment: It's no harder to reach the 'g' key than the apostrophe.  Just sayin'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After calling `realloc`, the contents of the newly allocated portion are indeterminate. This means that then calling `realloc` on the new rows may fail because it tries to reallocate an invalid pointer.

You can use `realloc` on the old rows and `malloc` on the new rows to fix this. Or you can zero the new part after the first `realloc`, and then your loop will work as is:

```
matr=realloc(matr, newmax*sizeof(matr*));
for (i=oldmax; i<newmax; i++)
    matr[i] = NULL;

for (i=0; i<newmax; i++){
    matr[i]=realloc(matr[i], newmax*sizeof(int));
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with "you can zero the new part"?

Comment: I added code to show this. It works because realloc behaves like malloc when passed a null pointer.

Comment: ok, that seems to work for now. the new segmentation fault is caused by something different, i think.